# Dynamically adding a Label is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I am attempting to dynamically create a profile page. Everything works fine except when I try to add the title (surrounded by `<h2>` tags) to the lbl control which is inserted in the select statement. Let me know if this is too confusing and I will attempt to explain further.

The point of the case statement is to create '1' heading for a particular position.

```
    mydiv = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV")
    tble.Rows.Add(trow)
    tCell = New TableCell
    tCell.ColumnSpan = 2
    tCell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Tan
    trow.Cells.Add(tCell)

    Select Case aUsers(x).Title
        Case 1
            If title <> "Members" Then
                title = "Members"
            End If
        Case 2
            If title <> "Treasurer" Then
                title = "Treasurer"
            End If
        Case 3
            If title <> "Secretary" Then
                title = "Secretary"
            End If
        Case 4
            If title <> "Membership Committee" Then
                title = "Membership Committee"
            End If
        Case 5
            If title <> "Vice President" Then
                title = "Vice President"
            End If
        Case 6
            If title <> "President" Then
                title = "President"
            End If
        Case Else
    End Select
    mydiv.InnerHtml = "<h2>" & title & "</h2>"
    tCell.Controls.Add(mydiv)
    trow = New TableRow
    tCell = New TableCell
    mydiv = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV")

    tble.Rows.Add(trow)
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding a label to the table cell working outside of the select statement but not inside

Comment: Is it that you aren't getting anything? If so, I would take a look at your SELECT CASE statement, and for debugging purposes write something out in the CASE ELSE block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not reading your code wrong, looks like you create an instance of label inside the case and set the text, but then for your second row your using the same instance and setting the text property.
You need to set lbl = New Label when you set your new rows and cells.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it - Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a label control as this writes a span tag, which is not a block level element whereas H* tags are. Html doesnt allow block level elements in non block elements. Use a Literal control instead. This only renders what text you assign (which can be html)

try this structure:

```
<td>
<h2>Name</h2>
<div class='bio'>
{bio}
</div>
</td>
```

also avoid using BR's and center tags for positioning/styling.. defer that to CSS, e.g.:

```
.bio {
  padding-top:10px
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sidestep the  tags entirely and assign a css class to the label.  In your CSS file, use the same style for both h2 and your new class.

Slight tangent:  Is this databound?  Looks like you have some dynamic data coming through which makes me think it might come from a bindable source.  If so, any reason not to use a databound control?

Comment: actually, I did try to use a repeater and a datagrid but Images are really tricky and I couldn't get them to display

Comment: Images should be no biggie.  Just use a template field.  You can get fine-grain control over rendering for each individual cell/row if you really need to.  Maybe post up a question with your image woes and we can help you out!  ;o)